# A well-supported wireless PCI adapter for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, adapter, pci

I need a PCI wireless adapter that works well with Ubuntu 12.04. I have looked around on the web but a lot of the information is out-of-date or confusing. Could someone point me to a wireless PCI adapter on Newegg or Amazon that they know works well with Ubuntu 12.04? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I am looking for a wireless PCI now for my desktop.  This is a great question.  The site for "WirelessCardsSupported" below hasn't been updated since some time in 2011, and a lot of the cards on that page are no longer in production, having been replaced by newer versions.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind It seems to me that the page is constantly updated

Answer (score 2):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Answer (score 1):

I went through several return/exchange cycles with both Amazon and Newegg, and finally found an adapter that works great on this site:

https://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/wireless-networking-gnulinux

I ended up getting this one:
https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/penguin-wireless-n-pcie-card

Comment: At the moment that card costs 99999.99 dollars :)